# Cant get SVG to scale properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Trying to add an svg file and have it scale from one end of the page to the other overlapping two divs (please see mock up image below)

Here is the page [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/j3jxvha5/1/)

Here is the code in particular:

HTML:

```
<!-- Sectional Blue Background -->
  <div id="blueSection">

  </div>

<!-- /Sectional Blue Background -->
```

CSS

```
    /* Blue Sectional 3 Steps */
#blueSection {
position: relative;
transform:scale(3, 4);
-webkit-transform:scale(3, 4);
-ms-transform: scale(3, 4);
right: 80em;
}

#blueSection::before {
content: '';
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: -80px;
left: 0;
background: url('http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/svg/blue.svg') no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
overflow: hidden;

}



#blueSection::after {
content: '';
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: -63px;
background: url('http://convio.cancer.ca/mIFE/svg/blue.svg') no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
    -ms-transform: rotate(5deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(5deg);
}
```

So what's happening right now is in full screen desktop mode, its right where I'd like it to be, however it extends all the way past the margins of the page. When you resize the screen it doesn't look at all the same its a completely different size. In mobile on chrome it's doesn't appear at all (havent tried other browsers). And in IE on desktop it's as if no edits were done to the blue section at all.

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong, if I need to use javascript/jquery or just css I don't mind going either route, I just want to learn how to fix this. I've looked at various articles and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

All suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time!

[image: Mockup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `background-size: cover` for both before and after elements.

Comment: interesting, cover continues to work but still stretches over creating a scroll, and when screen resizes it does get shorter in length, n disappears in mobile.

Comment: okay so reducing it to 2.1799 on the x-axis and keeping cover stops it from going off screen! ....so does that mean i have to keep adjusting for screen sizes with `@media inquiry`? there's gotta be faster way? :/

Comment: You want the aspect ratio to remain consistent?

Comment: ideally yes at least for desktop and tablet resizing, for mobile I'll just let the row collapse and colour the background blue lol